# How to make a batch script to back up a specific file with a unique destination folder (windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to set up an old game of mine (fallout new vegas 1.4.0.525) that I enjoy, however it is infamous for save file corruptions. What I'd like to ask is if it is possible to make a batch script that copies the save files and puts the copied save files in a folder for that particular set of backed up saves and assigns the folder a unique name based on the time the script is run. My OS is Windows 10.

Basically the process I'm looking for help with is

```
Script started -> New Folder with a timestamp for name created -> save copied files to the new folder.
```

The rough idea for the timecode I'm aiming for is HHDDMMYYYY (Ex. 1203042019)

The saves I wish the script to copy from are located in C:\Users-USER-\Documents\My Games\FalloutNV\Saves with the folders containing the backup saves being located in F:\Backups. The save files that need copying come in .fos and .nvse file types (.fos is the game's save file type and .nvse is a save file type created by a mod in addition to the regular save files for mod configuration)

If possible i'd like to know if the script can be run whenever I open up a specific program (Vortex, which is a mod manager and launcher) is opened.

Thanks very much in advance.

*edited for clairty*

Comment: There is not enough information given to answer your question. `1. What version of windows are you using? 2. What game and what version #? 3. Do you want the timestamp to be the date (040219)? The date with a time (040219-074200)? How precise do you want the time, do you want milliseconds (040219-0742001234)? 4. What are the file names to be saved? 5. Where do you want to save them?`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although written in PowerShell and not a batch file - this will work natively on Windows 10 without need for any plugins or extras.

I believe something similar to the below is what you are after.  In my example - Ive tried to include a lot of comments to get you started.  Its written in Powershell - so you would need to save the script as "myScript.ps1" and then create a shortcut on your deskop to "PowerShell.exe -File C:\users\me\whereeverthescriptis\myScript.ps1"

This will attempt a backup, launch the app if successful:

```
#What do you want to backup?
$sourceFolder = "C:\users\bbell\Desktop\p"
#Where do you want to backup to?
$destinationFolder = "C:\Installs"

#Figure out a destination folder with a timestamp.  Store it in a variable so that the same folder name is used throughout the script if it takes over a second to run
$destinationFolderWithTimestamp = ($destinationFolder + "\" + (Get-Date -Format yyyy-mm-dd_HH-mmmm-ss))

#if <destination folder>\<current date and time> doesn't exist - create it!
If (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationFolderWithTimestamp)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destinationFolderWithTimestamp
    Write-Host ($destinationFolderWithTimestamp + " Created")
}

try {
    #try a backup - stop if it fails
    Copy-Item -Recurse -Path $sourceFolder -Destination $destinationFolderWithTimestamp -ErrorAction Stop -force
    #confirm backup worked
    Write-Host "Backup Completed OK"
    #launch an app - in this case notepad - the "&" needs to be kept as it denotes launching something
    & C:\Windows\notepad.exe
} catch {
    #Error happened - inform user and do not launch
    Write-Host "Backup Failed - not launching app"
}
```